# Same equation, different results (Quartic function)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've encountered this equation:

$-5x(1+4x^2)^{-3/2}+{1\over\sqrt{1+4x^2}}=0$

I always use Cymath and Symbolab calculators, but this time they give different answers to the same equation.

[Symbolab result](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/-5x%5Cleft(1%2B4x%5E%7B2%7D%5Cright)%5E%7B-3%2F2%7D%2B1%2F%5Cleft(sqrt%5Cleft(1%2B4x%5E%7B2%7D%5Cright)%5Cright)%3D0)

[Cymath result](https://www.cymath.com/answer.php?q=-5x(1%2B4x%5E2)%5E(-3%2F2)%2B1%2F(sqrt(1%2B4x%5E2))%3D0)

I got the same result as Symbolab but by a different approach. I solve it by replacing the $x$ with $x^2$ and solving it as a quadratic function. (I hope you understand what I mean, not good at explaining things in english)

Questions:

- Which calculator is the correct?
- Is there any better calculator?

Bonus question: What is the point 9 doing in Cymath result? Any links that explains this property? I've been trying for hours to find out what it does...

Bonus content (my answer, check if correct please):

I reach a point where I'm left with: $16x^4-17x^2+1$
Then I do $u = x^2$

So: $16u^2-17u+1$

Then I do this:

$-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\over 2a$

And I get the results 1 and $1\over16$

So:

$x^2 = 1$ -> $x=\sqrt{1}$ -> $x=1$

$x^2 = {1\over16}$ -> $x=\sqrt{{1\over16}}$ -> $x={\sqrt{1}\over\sqrt{16}}$ -> $x={1\over4}$

Comment: In Cymath solution, look for the result after step 8, they suddenly reduced the order of the polynomial by 2. So they solved for $x^2$ instead of $x$. Just like you did. But afterwards when checking answers they didn't use that fact.

Comment: As for your  second question about step 9, well they used some intuition on how to simplify a polynomial with integer coefficients. My advice, unless you really see what's going on in there in terms of roots and such (see [Vieta's forumlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)), don't do that. You'll spend more time doing it. Instead use some more practical methods, like polynomial division or exact root formulas and etc.

Comment: @Kaster thank you very much! I was trying to find out what the ... the computer was doing in that step!

Comment: It is trying to factor the quadratic polynomial empirically, as I explained in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbolab does it OK.
Cymath changes the equation $16x^4-17x^2+1$ into $16x^2-17x+1$ between the steps 8 and 9 (software bug), so the answer is wrong.

At step 9, I guess Cymath is trying to write $16x^2-17x+1=(ax+1)(bx+1)=abx^2+(a+b)x+1$ and work out $a$ and $b$

I recommend Wolfram Alpha. It is much more reliable.

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-5x%281%2B4x^2%29^%28-3%2F2%29%2B1%2F%28sqrt%281%2B4x^2%29%29%3D0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-5x%281%2B4x%5E2%29%5E%28-3%2F2%29%2B1%2F%28sqrt%281%2B4x%5E2%29%29%3D0)

Comment: Okay, not trusting Cymath anymore! So it just like "forgets" about putting back the ^2 again? I'll try to report it as a bug.